# we are new to python opencv, we were given a video for underwater Buoys and it's required to detect these colored Buoys

Tags: python-3.7, opencv, python

detect underwater Buoys which are colored in red, green & yellow, we tried applying binary thresholding but that didn't work at all, Any help on how can we start or how to enhance the video and remove water color effect !!
this is the video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cV1gYDP-8SB6RhGybIYpAg5e0NCum51c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Access to your link is denied. Have you tried using cv2.inRange() on each color one at a time to threshold?

Comment: YOU MAY TRY THE LINK AGAIN
I tried this
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tLKb1x22-zrww3bkeSmc5wvA2Zl1WO4X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: but it shows no video!!
it says Process finished with exit code 0
 with no output!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your original link now works. You might be able to detect the red ball, but the other two are too close in color to the water color. They will be hard to detect by simple image processing methods.

Comment: I know.
that's why it's required to do some pre-processing first to try to restore the original colors.
to get something like this maybe https://drive.google.com/file/d/12yHhH4oU_Y3niPSIn7N6gdk0mnp8vWuW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The center ball is still too close in color to the water. So you will have a hard time extracting that.

Comment: The last image you posted can be converted to LAB and the luminance channel separated. It shows the balls well enough that you might be able to extract the buoys. You could look for circles above vertical posts. Perhaps multi-scale template matching might work. Or try Hough circles.

Comment: oh!
no, the last image is the enhanced one (that we should get to) , not the image that suppose to extract the buoys from. understand me !?

Comment: please post an original image (not video) so others can test with it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help, but one can remove color cast in an image by getting the average color and inverting it. Then copy that color to the image and blend the modified image with the original. Here is how to do that in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
#img = cv2.imread('2_1.jpg')
img = cv2.imread('cold.jpg')

# compute average color
mean = cv2.mean(img)[0:3]

# create average color image
average = np.full_like(img, (mean))

# create opposite (inverted) average color
opposite = 255 - average

# convert both images to HSV
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
opposite_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(opposite, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# copy the opposite hue and saturation channels to img_hsv
img_hsv[:,:,0] = opposite_hsv[:,:,0]
img_hsv[:,:,1] = opposite_hsv[:,:,1]

# convert img_hsv back to BGR
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# blend 50-50 with original img
result = cv2.addWeighted(img2, 0.5, img, 0.5, 0)

# save results
#cv2.imwrite('2_1_remove_color_cast.jpg', result)
cv2.imwrite('cold_remove_color_cast.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('average', average)
cv2.imshow('opposite', opposite)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

If I do the same with the one image you provided in your comment:

[image]

I get the result:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for the missunderstanding that happened here, it's my first time 
I will reformulate my question
the required is to enhance the video to make buoys appear in their real colors, green, yellow and red.
the above image is the enhanced one given to us by prof. , not us who enhanced it.
Is every thing clear now ?

Comment: Post an image that has not been enhance so I can test with the above method, if you want me to. If you do not care about this and it will not help you, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: this one from the video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hdox8oFuR_hKPxGX16DvpZwyGeQE8vbw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm searching too, so far i got to something named "CLAHE object" which might help, it's kind  of histogram equalization , but still don't know how exactly it works

Comment: I do not know if this is any better or helps, but I processed your image that you provided in your comment and put it in my answer above in place of the previous image.